# Strings and printf function

Tags: c

I'm in the process of learning C programming. I am in the process of creating a random text program and need some explanations.

```
 /*String*/
    const char* listG[] = { u8"Hello", u8"You", u8"I" };
    const char* listA[] = { u8"Fine", u8"Doing", u8"Bad" };
```

Would it be correct to call the above a string?

There's like 2 strings/categories, each time you run the program random words will pop-up and it'll give a sentence.

I don't understand the code below, could someone explain what it exactly does? What's the idea with this, what's the result, etc?

```
printf("%s %s.\n\n\n\n", listG[ran1], listA[ran2]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You really haven't provided enough information — what are `ran1`..`ran4`?  Are they created by invoking `rand() % 3` — or some other mechanism?  The `printf()` statement will print a random selection of strings from `ListG` in the first 4 words, and will repeat the first three words as strings 5-7.  Not very exciting, but then the list of strings isn't very big.  (And the example shows the same characters in each string, so the output will be even less exciting.)

Comment: You've simplified the question (that's good), but you've not provided the missing information I mentioned — what are `ran1` and `ran2`?  How are they given values?  The basic explanation is much the same as before; the `printf()` statement will print two words on a line, followed by some blank lines.  Assuming `ran1` and `ran2` are random numbers in the appropriate range, the first word will be one of the words in `listG` and the second will be one of the words in `listA`.  It isn't clear to me what problem you're having understanding that?

Comment: Each of `listA` and `listG` is an array of pointers to characters; they contain pointers to strings because of the way they're initialized.  The elements of the array are strings; the arrays themselves are not strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes the ran1..ran2 as you posted earlier they're created by invoking rand() % 3.

Thanks for trying to help, makes more sence now, I had problem understanding the listG[ran1]. Instead of writing listG[ran1] and listA[ran2] could I instead just do: list[ran1] and list[ran2]? It might sound stupid, sorry ;) Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, so what I understand is that the lists are arrays of pointers to the characters located in the array itself? So just make it clear, so those are the characters[u8"Hello", u8"You", u8"I"]? And  const char* listG[] = {}; is the array of pointers?

Comment: You can't write `list[ran1]` because there is no array `list` to index into.  If there was a single list called `list`, then you could write `list[ran1]` and `list[ran2]` and there'd be no problem — remember to change the modulo operation from 3 to the new combined list size.  The variables `listA` and `listG` are both arrays (of pointers to `char`); the pointers are initialized to point at the `u8"data"` strings listed in the initializers.  `ListA[0]` points at the `F` of `u8"Fine"`, and is colloquially said to point at the string `u8"Fine"`, but it is a bit sloppy to say so.